# ¿Cómo mostrar un checkbox marcado mediante JSON?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, json

Acá podemos ver como se ingresa el `checkbox` en html y hay un botón para mostrar que se conecta a un `.js` mediante una función llamado buscar.

```
<label>DNI</label>
    <input type="text" id="dni">
    <label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre">
    <label>APELLIDO</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido">
    <label>CELULAR</label>
    <input type="text" id="numero"><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <label>MARCA</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="huawei" value="huawei"/> huawei
    <input type="checkbox" id="lg" value="lg"/> lg
    <input type="checkbox" id="nokia" value="nokia"/>  nokia
    <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">
```

En la función trate de llamar valores mediante `JSON`, osea que al momento de ingresar el DNI me muestre los datos de la BD, pero no me muestra los `checkbox` que estaban marcados al momento de ingresar datos.

```
function buscar(){

    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}
    $.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
                $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
            $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
            $("#numero").val(d[2]);
            ///$("#huawei").html('<input type="checkbox" id="'+d[3]+'" value="'+d[3]+'" checked="checked">');
            ///$("#lg").html('<input type="checkbox" id="'+d[4]+'" value="'+d[4]+'" checked="checked">');
        ///$("#nokia").html('<input type="checkbox" id="'+d[5]+'" value="'+d[5]+'" checked="checked">');
////el problema es en la funcion ya que no llama a mis checkbox que fueron //marcados(huawei,lg,nokia) quisiera saber si hay algun codigo que sirva para //llamar a un checkbox asi como se llama a valor ingresado en caja de texto
            }
        });
}
```

Aquí conecto a mi base de datos y hago el llamado de datos de la BD.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("archivos",$con);

$dni=$_POST["dni"];
$rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie WHERE dni='$dni'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'], $row['apellido'], $row['numero'], $row['huawei'], $row['lg'], $row['nokia']);
//, $row['huawei'], $row['lg'], $row['nokia']
echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
?>
```

El problema es en la función ya que no llama a mis `checkbox` que fueron marcados.

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida te invito a leer **[ask]**

Comment: A ver si te entiendo, lo que quieres es al recuperar la data del servicio, poder pintar los checkbox con los valores marcados o desmarcados segun la data que viaja en el servicio? Podrias favor subir el HTML de tu solución? esto me serviria para poder brindarte una mejor solución.

Comment: @DelcioManuelPolancoPadilla, creo que subió el HTML, pero no se ve porque no fue subido como código... (están editando la pregunta, toca esperar -_-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacer una validacion para saber si el dato fue seleccionado ejemplo:
det tu base retornas el campo **lg, huawei..etc** 
cada uno debe tener un valor para saber si se selecciono por el cliente es decir:

```
 1 -> seleccionado, 0-> no seleccionado
```

basados en eso haria algo asi:

```
    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}
    $.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
                $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
            $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
            $("#numero").val(d[2]);
            //verifico si fue seleccionado por el usuario
            if (d[3]=="1"){
            //establezco el checked
            document.getElementById("huawei").checked = true;
             }//end if
           //asi con el resto
            }
        });
```

ojo esto es basdo en una flg o bandera 1 -> seleccionado 0-> no seleccionado, alli debes validar segun tu logica del campo de mysql. suerte !

Comment: una consulta, esto que usted hizo para un checkbox funciono correctamente, pero cual seria el codigo en ajax para mantener marcado los check de una variable tipo "multiple"                           <input multiple="multiple" id="especial" /> 
    <option>Huawei</option<>
    <option>lg</option<>                                                                                              
    <option>lg</option<>